# rewrite URL to new one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My URL is retrieving DB content and the link as below

```
http://mydomain/page.php?id=number&link=newurl
```

And want to have my new URL to be

```
http://newurl
```

FYI: newurl including mydomain

Also is there a way to have the visitor visit the page using my new URL, or not?

Comment: if you only use `http://example.com/newurl` then how will your php get the `id` parameter? It will need to be included in the URL something like `http://example.com/123/newurl`

Comment: OK, if I configured it like this, how to rewrite the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of answers for this here on SO for your *exact* scenario already. This is a very common request. So this will work for this type of link

```
http://example.com/123/newurl
```

Use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?id=$1&link=$2 [L]
```